# Formatting SMS Message in PHP

Tags: android, android-studio, sms, phpmailer, string-formatting

I have this code:

```
mail(111222333@vtext.com, "A message", ("<i>test</i>"), implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

I want the message to be italicized: Currently, it is just like the other texts.

***EDIT:*** If initialization isn't possible, can I make a space between my header and line like...

> A message
>
> test

Answer (score 1):

SMS just does text, that's all. There is no styling, it's not HTML.

That said, if your clients support unicode, there is a workaround - there are things like italic and bold characters defined *as characters* rather than as applied styles, for example this text:

> 

Is using unicode italic characters, not the markdown styling available in Stack Overflow.

There are lots of other things you can do, such as , , ⓒⓘⓡⓒⓛⓔⓓ, -, but whether it works for your recipients will be extremely variable. Take a look at sites like [this](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/text.html) and [this](https://yaytext.com/bold-italic/), which also includes example renderings from various clients.

Comment: Is there a way where I can make a space between texts? @Synchro

Comment: See my answer to your other question.